# How to declare timestamp only once in php or laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm working on passing a timestamp to a page. Basically What I'm doing is get the current time in my controller and then passing it to the view. But the problem I have is that after the time stamp is render in the view and if I refresh the page I get different time. So is there anyway to just show a timestamp only ONCE and not let change by loading the page?? Thanks in advance:

Here's my code:

**HomeController.php**

```
public function orderingSubmissionReceipt()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('MST7MDT');
    $currentDateTime = date("F j, Y H:i:s");

    return view('order-summary', [
        'currentDateTime' => $currentDateTime
    ]);
 }
```

**order-summary.blade.php**

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $currentDateTime ?></div>
```

Comment: save it in the session, only if not set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use session:

```
if(!session('current_date_time')) {
   session(['current_date_time', date("F j, Y H:i:s")]);
}

return view('order-summary', [
    'currentDateTime' => session('current_date_time')
]);
```

That will set the current datetime in session the first time, and from there on it will use the same value.

You can read more about Laravel's session management here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Comment: that worked , but after I log out and log in again the session time is still the same. How to clear the session after login out? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read through the Laravel documentation link I provided? You should really get familiar with the docs on all this. To answer your question, `session()->flush()` will clear all data from session. Or of course you could do `session()->forget('current_date_time');` to just clear this one stored piece of data.

Comment: Thanks bro!. I'm accepting your answer as the correct one.